# How to manually install a theme for KCacheGrind?

Tags: kde, themes, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I just installed KCacheGrind onto my WSL2 Ubuntu for profiling the performance of a program, but I can't stand the blinding light.

I've noticed that every time I run it through the terminal, there is the message `Icon theme "breeze" not found.` (but the program works just fine). Then I learned about KDE themes, but I don't want to install the whole KDE ecosystem. I just want to install a dark theme so that I can use KCacheGrind comfortably.

I found many KDE themes online available as GitHub repos. So I downloaded [gnome-breeze](https://github.com/dirruk1/gnome-breeze) which has the folder "Breeze-dark-gtk" consisting of a dark theme. In my understanding, all that is left to do is for me to figure out where exactly to put the files so that they are recognized as a theme. I've learned that they are to be stored in `~/.themes` (or `/usr/share/themes`), but couldn't find more info on the exact directory structure. I have tried a bunch of guesses (such as `mv gnome-breeze/Breeze-dark-gtk ~/.themes/breeze`), but the theme is still not recognized.

I don't need to be able to switch between multiple themes. If I can trick KCacheGrind into thinking that a custom dark theme is the default theme and apply it to its GUI, that's all I want.

Comment: It is the desktop core that is responsible for applying themes, If what you want was possible you would need a KCacheGrind  theme. Browser have their own theme. So does LO. But smaller projects depend on the core. "profiling the performance of a program" I doubt you need a gui to orofile a command :)

Comment: @Rinzwind Hmm... Then I wonder why there is the message `Icon theme "breeze" not found.` as if it simply checked whether some files exist. Also, KCacheGrind is part of the standard KDE bundle, and somebody in an online forum was asked about his dark KCacheGrind theme, and he replied (paraphrasing:) "I don't know, it's just like this from the start, consistent with my overall desktop theme."

Well, it seems that you haven't done much profiling beyond measuring overall runtime... Check out KCacheGrind and you'll [see how cool it is.](https://kcachegrind.sourceforge.net/html/Screenshots.html)